# How to set values for several columns without loop

Tags: python, pandas

How can I set values for several columns without loop?

```
df.loc[:, ['test2', 'test3']] = 0
```

or

```
df[['test2', 'test3']] = 0
```

I expect it to set values 0 in columns 'test2' and 'test3', but it returns the error, that there is no such columns in the df.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to create new columns you can use [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.assign(test1=0,test2=0)
```

This will create 2 columns with values as `0`

Comment: Dont forget to assign it back to the df. `df=df. assign(..) `

Answer (score 1):

`df.assign()` is a great way as suggested by @anky_91 to do a bunch of columns at once.

Another explicit way is direct column assignment but then it's column by column

```
df["NewCol1"] = 0
df["NewCol2"] = 0
```

Sometimes it's convenient for when you need a single new column.